# detect XHR on a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a Chrome extension, just imagine when Facebook loads you are allowed to add extra JS on it.

But my problem is I can't modify the DOM of the later content, which means the newly loaded content that appear when the user scrolled down.

So I want to detect XHR using JavaScript.

I tried

```
send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {

    /* Wrap onreadystaechange callback */
    var callback = this.onreadystatechange;
    this.onreadystatechange = function() {             
         if (this.readyState == 4) {
             /* We are in response; do something, like logging or anything you want */
                        alert('test');
         }
         callback.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    _send.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

But this is not working.. any ideas?

Comment: you have a variable name mismatch `send` and `_send`

Comment: `send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;` and `_send.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: looks the value of `callback` is null

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dy58ud0c/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny is the callback important? I just want to detect whether there is an ajax event happening..

Comment: in ur code I alert instead of console, it failed, why?

Comment: can you tell us what is that you want to do in the ajax handler...

Comment: @ArunPJohny use some $('.class').text('to change something).. an alert should work within that right?

Comment: if you are using jQuery look at the jQuery global events... like [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny cannot coz fb isn't using jquery..

Comment: I can help you, but I would appreciate if you cleaned up your question first. Make a best attempt at proper English, and I will answer.

Comment: @Xan please.. I'd been searching for the answer for few days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides Arun's correct remark that you should use `_send` for both, your approach doesn't work because of how Content Scripts work.

The code running in the content script works in an [isolated environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), to prevent it from conflicting with page's own code. So it's not like you described - you're not simply adding JS to the page, you have it run isolated. As a result, your XHR replacement only affects XHR calls from your extension's content scripts and not the page.

It's possible to [inject the code into the page itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script). This will affect XHR's from the page<del>, but might not work on all pages, if the Content Security Policy of the page in question disallows inline code. It seems like Facebook's CSP would allow this.</del> Page's CSP should not be a problem according to [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#interactions). So, this approach should work, see the question I linked.

---

That said, you're not specifically looking for AJAX calls, you're looking for new elements being inserted in the DOM. You can detect that without modifying the page's code, using [DOM MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/934239) for more information.

Comment: what is the CSP of Facebook?

Comment: @user3522749 It's a HTTP response header. Open up Dev Tools, navigate to Facebook, and examine the Network panel. It's too long to post here.

Answer (score 1):

to detect AJAX calls on a webpage you have to inject the code directly in that page and then call the `.ajaxStart` or `.ajaxSuccess`

Example:

```
// To Successfully Intercept AJAX calls, we had to embed the script directly in the Notifications page
var injectedCode = '(' + function() {
    $('body').ajaxSuccess(function(evt, request, settings) {
        if (evt.delegateTarget.baseURI == 'URL to check against if you want') {
            // do your stuff
        }
    });
} + ')();';
// Inserting the script into the page
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = injectedCode;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Comment: It would be better if you included a relevant example from your code in your answer(s).

Comment: Great, upvoted both. Be careful with promoting own code, this can provoke a trigger-happy reaction from SO community, but this now is definitely a useful answer.

Comment: thanks a lot @Xan .. will be aware of that in the future

Comment: I tried this, ajaxSuccess didn't work because facebook didn't use jquery.. I don't know that in detail but as other said, facebook isn't using jquery so it doesn't work. Anyway, thx @AhmadAssaf for your input!

Comment: how about you try this https://gist.github.com/creotiv/469941. You still need to do the injection of the code